# Can I connect two other monitors to my Dell Studio XPS?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, displayport, dell-xps

I currently have a Dell Studio XPS laptop that I connect to an external monitor with the standard VGA output.   I have also bought a Display port to DVI adaptor that I would like to connect to another monitor.

I have Windows 7 and have been unable to get windows to extend the desktop to both of the external monitors at once.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Studio XPS has a Radeon HD5730, which should support Eyefinity. Using the VGA port and DisplayPort simultaneously should be possible; however, you will not be able to use the built-in display at the same time. You can either have the internal display and one external display, or two external displays, but not all three. If that still isn't working, try updating your graphics drivers to the latest version *from ATI* (not from Dell's site) and see if it works then.

Comment: I see, so it can only do any two displays, not two external plus internal?

Comment: Right, the internal reason for this boils down to the fact that there's only a pair of RAMDAC's within the card itself. The RAMDAC is the physical memory locations which the card has which are turned into the display. (they probably aren't called RAMDAC's anymore since they aren't turned into analog signals) - but the point remains the same, there simply aren't enough "internal video memory->display" components on the video card.

Comment: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/video/modes_Refresh.htm

Comment: Ah yes, they are called TMDS now -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_Minimized_Differential_Signaling

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.  So the only solution is to have an external device that will handle the extra displays.

Answer (score 2):

The other solution would be to use an external graphics card, from USB out, such as the ones found below.

[Best external graphics cards 2021](https://dotesports.com/hardware/news/the-7-best-external-graphics-cards-egpus-in-2021)

Comment: I didn't know such an external card existed

Comment: The link in this answer is dead, it redirects to an irrelevant page.